# Returning multiple ints and passing them as multiple arguements in Lua

Tags: syntax, parameters, lua

I have a function that takes a variable amount of ints as arguments.

```
thisFunction(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,7,4,2)
```

this function was given in a framework and I'd rather not change the code of the function or the .lua it is from. So I want a function that repeats a number for me a certain amount of times so this is less repetitive. Something that could work like this and achieve what was done above

```
thisFunction(repeatNum(1,3),repeatNum(2,4),3,repeatNum(4,2),7,4,2)
```

is this possible in Lua? I'm even comfortable with something like this:

```
thisFunction(repeatNum(1,3,2,4,3,1,4,2,7,1,4,1,2,1))
```

Comment: By the way, it's 'Lua', not 'LUA'.

Comment: sorry, I know that but it was how I was introduced to it by a professor who doesn't know the difference. Old habits die hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're stuck with something along the lines of your second proposed solution, i.e.

```
 thisFunction(repeatNum(1,3,2,4,3,1,4,2,7,1,4,1,2,1))
```

because if you use a function that returns multiple values in the middle of a list, it's adjusted so that it only returns one value. However, at the end of a list, the function does not have its return values adjusted.

You can code `repeatNum` as follows. It's not optimized and there's no error-checking. This works in Lua 5.1. If you're using 5.2, you'll need to make adjustments.

```
function repeatNum(...)
     local results = {}
     local n = #{...}
     for i = 1,n,2 do
       local val = select(i, ...)
       local reps = select(i+1, ...)
       for j = 1,reps do
          table.insert(results, val)
       end
     end
     return unpack(results)
end
```

I don't have 5.2 installed on this computer, but I believe the only change you need is to replace `unpack` with `table.unpack`.

Comment: If all your numbers are non-negative then negative numbers can be used as repeat commands: `thisFunction(repNum(1,-3,2,-4,3,4,-2,7,4,2))`

Comment: You should replace `n=#{...}` with `n=select("#",...)` since the first solution creates a table just to compute the number of arguments and then discards it (it creates useless garbage). Moreover it doesn't play well if some argument is `nil` (this is probably not an issue in this case, but it's worth pointing it out). Another efficiency trick is `results[#results+1]=val` to append a value to `results`: it is faster than calling `table.insert` (this may be important since it is called in a nested loop, YMMV).

Answer (score 1):

I realise this question has been answered, but I wondered from a readability point of view if using tables to mark the repeats would be clearer, of course it's probably far less efficient.

```
function repeatnum(...)
    local i = 0
    local t = {...}
    local tblO = {}
    for j,v in ipairs(t) do
        if type(v) == 'table' then
           for k = 1,v[2] do
               i = i + 1
               tblO[i] = v[1]
           end
        else
           i = i + 1
           tblO[i] = v
        end
    end
    return unpack(tblO)
end
print(repeatnum({1,3},{2,4},3,{4,2},7,4,2))
```